# ERROR: Could not connect. SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

I receive this error on my remote site

ERROR: Could not connect. SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I feel like I'm so close to figuring it out and I know it has a problem to do with my `config-remote.php` file which looks exactly the same as my regular `config.php`...

```
<?php

$host       = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$dbname     = "real_Database"; 
$dsn        = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname"; 
$options    = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
              );

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
try{
    $pdo_connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

I am aware the `config-remote.php` file needs to be different to the regular `config.php` file. The site works perfectly on my local host obviously, however I have no idea where to find the info to replace the host, username, password and dbname in `config-remote.php`. I need to be able to submit the remote URL for other people to view. I have transferred all files from local to remote on FileZilla. So this seems to be the only thing holding me back.

Comment: Do you have a database set up on for your remote site?

Comment: @finiteloop yes I believe I do, I'm just new to coding so not sure where that is? cPanel on SiteGround possibly ?

Comment: what hosting provider are you using?

Comment: im using SiteGround

Comment: did that help?  Do you have a database already set up?

Comment: thanks @finiteloop im having a look now

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @finiteloop the link you provided didn't directly help, turns out I needed technical assistance, site is up and running now anyway. Thanks for the help

Comment: glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

@Kryptic1

Check this link here, which will show you how to create a database in SiteGround.

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/create-user-database

If you do not have one already set up this should help you get started and then you will be able to take note of the host, user, password, etc.

If you do happen to already have one set up on SiteGround, I imagine that will also end up pointing you in the right direction because you should be able to figure out what the host, user, and password is (or reset the password from there if need be).

Once you have the appropriate details, you will then be able to edit your `config-remote.php` file with the appropriate credentials, save it and then re-upload it using Filezilla.

Answer (score -1):

Possible error is that the password you are using is wrong. Try login using the terminal `mysql -uroot -p`   then enter your `password` when asked to confirm if you are using the right credentials.